# Nested associations failing on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to set up nested associations ( with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ) in Rails 3, but `save` is failing without showing any errors on the model.

`db/schema.rb`:

```
create_table "question_responses", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "answer"
  t.boolean  "correct"
  t.integer  "question_id"
  t.integer  "quiz_result_id"
end

create_table "quiz_results", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "student_id"
  t.integer  "quiz_id"
  t.text     "message"
end
```

`question_response.rb`:

```
class QuestionResponse < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :quiz_result, :inverse_of => :question_responses

  validates :question, :presence => true
  validates :quiz_result, :presence => true

  before_save :check_answer
end
```

`quiz_result.rb`:

```
class QuizResult < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :quiz, :presence => true
  validates :student, :presence => true
  validates :quiz_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :student_id }
  validate :student_teacher

  belongs_to :quiz
  belongs_to :student
  has_many :question_responses, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :quiz_result
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_responses

end
```

Any suggestions for how I can get this working?

server output:

```
Started POST "/quiz_results" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-20 10:20:24 +0000
Processing by QuizResultsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YceTVCh/GxdReb3KRMNj+cJhm6k0jwhsHl3LcJlSDJM=", "quiz_result"=>{"student_id"=>"695735877", "quiz_id"=>"17663260", "question_responses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"question_id"=>"14376743", "answer"=>"test"}}}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 113461968]]
  Student Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = 695735877 LIMIT 1
  Teacher Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "teachers".* FROM "teachers" WHERE "teachers"."id" = 657318460 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Quiz Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "quizzes".* FROM "quizzes" WHERE "quizzes"."id" = 17663260 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = 695735877 LIMIT 1
  QuizResult Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "quiz_results" WHERE ("quiz_results"."quiz_id" = 17663260 AND "quiz_results"."student_id" = 695735877) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "teachers".* FROM "teachers" WHERE "teachers"."id" = 657318460 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "teachers".* FROM "teachers" WHERE "teachers"."id" = 657318460 LIMIT 1
  Question Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = 14376743 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "quiz_results" ("created_at", "message", "quiz_id", "student_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 20 Mar 2012 10:20:24 UTC +00:00], ["message", nil], ["quiz_id", 17663260], ["student_id", 695735877], ["updated_at", Tue, 20 Mar 2012 10:20:24 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  QuestionResponse Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "question_responses".* FROM "question_responses" WHERE "question_responses"."quiz_result_id" IS NULL
  Rendered quiz_results/_form.html.haml (5.0ms)
  Rendered quiz_results/new.html.haml within layouts/application (6.8ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 113461968]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 113461968]]
  Student Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = 695735877 LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 13.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

Comment: when is it failing, please post the command and the backtrace so it can be debugged

Comment: Failing in the `create` action, on `save`, with apparently no errors on the model. Added the log to op.

Answer (score 0):

Use validates_associated: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_associated